# What are the shia narrations for sun rise and sunset between horns of devils?

Tags: shiism, shia-sunni

Sunni have narrations indicating prohibition of voluntary worship during sunrise and sunset.
And narrations mentioning the sunrise and sunset occurring between horns of devil.

Ibn ‘Umar (may Allah be pleased with him) reported that the Messenger of Allah (may Allah’s peace and blessings be upon him) said: "When the edge of the sun rises, avoid prayer until it becomes prominent; and if the edge of the sun disappears, avoid prayer until it sets. And do not offer your prayer at the time of sunrise or sunset, for it rises between two horns of a devil – or the devil."
[Sahih/Authentic] - [Al-Bukhari and Muslim]

Do ithna ashari have similar narration?

Google search isn't giving any results

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the Shia do not have such an opinion
The late Khoei'(From Shia scholars), in connection with the abhorrence of the Nailah etiquette of the beginners "after the morning prayer until sunrise and after the evening prayer until sunset", said that the abhorrence of prayer was not proven in these two times.